# Titanium - Not able to stop iOs background process

Tags: ios, geolocation, titanium, titanium-mobile, background-process

I already implement background service for my app. I am using it for getting user current location by using location services.

I will explain the way i implement this - "XYZ.js" - Screen where user distance display. Following code is added to set register background service -

```
var iService = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({
            url : 'BackgroundService.js'
        });
```

once app go to background, background service start and collect user locations. When app come is at foreground i fired following event -

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('stopBackgroundService');
```

In "BackgroundService.js" - there is listener as -

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('stopBackgroundService',function(){
    Ti.App.currentService.stop();
});
```

But after finishing this all location base work, when i move to other screen and taking app to background, location services start again. Due to Which device battery drains.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with it, I solved it by following way -
1. Create global variable as

```
`Ti.App.BackgroundService`
```

1. assign service to above variable
2. when location services based work finish, stop and unregister background service as

   Ti.App.BackgroundService.stop();

It works as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To stop background process all you need is to call [Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService.unregister()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService-method-unregister)